# Calling base class methods from InitializeComponent

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a prototype based forms application, where there will be a base template to use for all forms. There is a method in template, which needs to be called by the actual form, while constructing the controls.

Form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : FormBase
{
    public Form1():base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    ...
```

Form1.Designer.cs:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.lblName = new MLabel();
    this.fldName = new MTextBox();
    this.lblUserID = new MLabel();
    this.fldUserID = new MTextBox();

    this.SuspendLayout();

    this.AddControl(lblName, fldName);
    this.AddControl(lblUserID, fldUserID);
```

FormBase.cs:

```
public partial class FormBase : Form
{
    public FormBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected void AddControl(Label lbl, Control ctrl)
    {
        //do something
    }
    ...
```

There are no compilation errors, however, when I open the Form1 design in IDE, it says FormBase.AddControl not found. Even when I run the app, the method didn't seem called.

Thanks.

Comment: **Never** edit the code in InitializeComponent().  You'll either lose the changes when the designer rewrites the method or you'll bomb the designer when it can't parse your changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the method **AddControl** from Form1.cs, don't call it from **Form1.Designer.cs**

please let me know if that way still failed. :)

Comment: The intention why I was trying to call from designer is I can see the design in IDE, so that I can make changes with ease. Anyhow, I will check with calling from the form.

Comment: oh, so what do you want is to replace some auto generated part in the InitializeComponent method of Form1.Designer.cs appropriate with your template?

Comment: It is not recommended to place your code in the InitializeComponent method, because when you play with your designer UI, it will be replaced automatically.

Comment: It is not recommended to place your code in the InitializeComponent method, because when you play with your designer UI, it will be replaced automatically.
but.... for sure, it still posible. 
Just change the access modifier of your AddControl method to public. now you can see your changes on design time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the second alternate:

just change this part

```
protected void AddControl(Label lbl, Control ctrl)
{
    //do something
}
```

into this:

```
public void AddControl(Label lbl, Control ctrl)
{
    //do something
}
```